# Waiting the function to be done in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, function, execution

There is a function like this:

```
public MImage ImageHandler (parameter){
    // do something
}
```

This function will take some time depending on the parameter, now I want to monitor the execution of this function and do something after the function is done, like this:

```
//call this function
Task task = new task(ImageHandler(parameter));
task.begin();
task.done +=(()={ // do something after the function is done});
```

So How can I make it out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your code that takes some time to execute on a background thread using a `BackgroundWorker`

See: [How to use a BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

The code that you want to run after the task has been complete can be placed in teh handler for the `RunWorkerCompleted` event.

Answer (score -1):

you can make a event in your function. and += it .